# DataReader, DataAdapter & DataSet - When to use?

Tags: ado.net, dataset, datareader, dataadapter

I want to know when i have to use these ADO.NET Components???can anyone brief it with an example???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googled those three words.. got an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217202925/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37618.aspx) with the same title as your post.

[Here's](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html) another article with some code to look at.